# Magento 2.2.7 - attribute is being save in default template when I don't want it there

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I am sure this is a simple question but it seems for the last week I have not been able to find it out I am using Magento 2.2.7 and when I used the color attribute then made an attribute set. I move the color attribute into the set. 
Now I made a configurable product from the default template and added in the color attribute group. Now I think this is where I am getting messed up. the last page has 3 saves and the default is first, which I saved it to. This must be wrong however when I tried to use the other two it asks to save as if I put color, then states that color is already used. Shouldn't this overwrite as I will have many different save then? What am I doing wrong, I am totally missing something here. 
[Product I made last](https://www.stuffwholesale.com/copper-or-gold-bling-10mm-cz-necklace-and-earring-set.html)
Thanks
Ron

Comment: Hi Ron. Is really difficult to understand exactly what you are asking. Could you rephrase?

Comment: Hi and thank you but it seem that I have found out the problem. When I make a configurable product I did not follow the exact steps. I used default as instead of the attribute tab and then made the product and used the configurable and click the attribute and saved. which put the attribute in the default. I know I am not to good at explaining I am sorry. But it is fixed and thanks again for answering.